# Why do (bgl) exceptions in modal crash blender

Tags: python, add-on, opengl

No matter what I type into the console, or execute from the text buffer, blender shows an error but continues on as usual. However, I recently noticed that many exceptions (involving bgl callbacks) make blender crash **if they happen inside the modal operator**.

Why is that?

Comment: care to elaborate on the code in the modal function? bgl callbacks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### bgl callbacks

The modal part of your operator needs to return something each time it's called, in the case of an exception that is probably `return {'CANCELLED'}`. Most exceptions are not fatal, but exceptions in *bgl callbacks* can be.

One crash is one too many, you might have to stick in a [try/except (with traceback)](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/traceback.html), at least until you find the cause of the exception in the bgl callback and find a way to prevent it, you also need to correct the GL state before the callback function ends. Else expect undefined behaviour.

Comment: Yes, bgl callbacks indeed, but I was more curious as to why it isn't "safety-wrapped" like the other execution contexts, than looking for a solution. I did co with try/except blocks, no worries.

Comment: modal bgl is one of the few scenarios where i've seen pretty gruesome 'close to desktop'  style crashing. Solved by correcting the logic in the bgl callback.. I think you are right to ask why that should be any different, it perhaps deserves a dedicated question, or rename your question to include the term _involving exceptions in bgl callbacks_

Comment: I might do that later today